# Swarm Host/Hydra/Viper vs. Siege Tank/Banshee/Viking

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

When I play Zerg and use a Swarm Host/Hydra/Viper build I always lose to SiegeTank/Banshee/Viking.

1. The Terran players uses his Vikings to kill my overseers before my hydra can get in position.
2. Then he uses cloaked banshees to kill hydra and swarm host in conjunction with scanners.
3. His siege tanks can take out my locust if they are behind a supply depot wall-in.
4. My vipers can't get to the siege tanks to abduct them because of the vikings.

Is there a better strategy to deal with this when I have already committed to it? Would mass spore crawlers be better around my swarm host? How about a nydus worm drop in the back of his base.

Alos I am constantly supply blocked because his vikings are killing my overseers faster than I can produce them.

Comment: perhaps an infestor switch to fungal his air in place (and break the banshee's cloak) and let the hydras go to town

Comment: I will try that, but I have pretty poor micro at the moment. (I am in Bronze league)

Comment: I don't think this unit composition is very viable against Terran.

Comment: @Decency It worked amazingly well verses MMM with a few siege tanks. I don't know if this is just a bad opponent, but it worked for me.

Comment: @jacen.garriss Swarm hosts in general are just weak against Terran after midgame because they'll just have so many scans, and larger MMM balls will just clean it up. Most builds in lower level games are just about who has more stuff, rather than whose stuff is a better composition. For learning to macro better, I'd find a good build order like the one I posted in your last topic and try to master that, rather than worrying about higher level concepts like countering with multi-unit compositions.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't the answer everyone could use, but I think you should take it account as a lower level player. I think your problem is not a tactical one of how to win with that composition vs that composition, but a strategic one of not ending up in the situation at all.

If you are currently in bronze league, it sounds like you are making things a little too complicated a little too fast. You should start out just practicing macro, since you should be able to simply A-move your opponents to death with decent macro. Trying to micro a multi-faceted army against a superior unit position is going to be a lot less sucessful for you than simply making sure you have a bigger army, sooner.

My guess is the reason that you are in this situation is because you are not scouting, or harassing enough, you are probably teching up to your final composition without enough information. If you concentrate on a build that involves earlier pressure, you can determine whether the terran is building lots of factories/starports. If they aren't, you can feel safe to go into your current build, and you should find a new build for situations where they do have a mech heavy build.

The benefit to that early pressure is that at low skill levels it will frequently outright kill your opponent, just because they aren't good at defense against early attacks.

Answer (score 0):

To help you on the questions at hand.

1. Have your overseers on follow on your Hydras (do so by right
   clicking the overseer on the Hydra) And make sure the Overseer is in the midle of your group of units. The Viking outrange the Hydralisks by range 4. (3).
2. Never engage off creep vs. a Terran. Force him to come to you unto
   the creep for vision. You can build Spines and Spores to aid you in
   combat. The Spines works like a charm vs. Banshees.
3. The locusts should be considered expendeble, and are in this case,
   used to draw fire off your Hydras. Its a good thing that they are
   fired upon by the enemy Tanks.
4. The above points should help you regarding the Vikings. Try to
   upduct the Vikings too, into your Hydras.

Like Lawton mentioned, try not to make it too complicated for you at this stage. 
In regards of you Overlords, make sure you have ekstra supplies. Do this by rallying your new Overlords into the mid of your main base. Just make massive amounts of Overlords too. (not too many)

When you face a Terran who goes for Tank Viking and Banshee, it might be a respons to your build. But if you face a Terran with this build anyways, I would as a Zerg go for Speedlings and Mutas.

If the Terran adds bio units, and Banelings to your army with speed!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Some of these weren't viable in my game where my opponent did this, but I will try to do some of these later. I did do the first point. The second was harder to do,because I have horrible macro and couldn't get me creep there even after 30 minutes of play. The third I will try to do next game, and the last I couldn't do because he had 30 vikings compared to my 4 vipers. He would target them over anything else because I would abduct his tanks. Overall thank you for the tips.

Comment: @jacen.garriss Theres an answer regarding playing the basics of Zerg. I wrote an answere there I think you could find usefull.

Comment: yep, I know. I have read that and many other post here. I know what to do mostly, but have a hard time putting it in action.

Comment: @jacen.garriss StarCraft 2 is a lot of stuff happening at the same time. My all over recommendations to you would be to learn one thing to perfection, and then focus on the next thing. Like making sure your never supply bloged, then moving on to handeling Drone production and expansions. Then your creep etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks it just takes time. I started school this week, so I have even less time, but I will get these down eventually.

Comment: Maybe we should try playing together sometime, and you could do some coaching?

Comment: @jacen.garriss We could do that. Let me know what your ingame nick is and #. Ill log onto the US server some day!

Comment: my nick is sonofpaint. I will have to find my # next time I get on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10390/discussion-between-jacen-garriss-and-atlaseu)